# Unable to find a solution for 2d nonlinear heat equation in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, 2d, equation, heat

Please help me to find a solution in a Wolfram Mathematica program. 
I have several times checked the accuracy of the entered data. They are true. The solution must exist. But a Wolfram provides either the empty graph (for any point in time), or an error "NDSolve::eerr". Here is my code:

```
    solution = 
 NDSolve[{D[fun[t, x, y], t] == 
    Exp[-t]*Cos[Pi*y] + D[fun[t, x, y], {x, 2}] + 
     D[fun[t, x, y], {y, 2}], fun[t, 0, y] == 0, fun[t, 1, y] == 0, 
   fun[0, x, y] == 0, (D[fun[t, x, y], y] /. y -> 0) == 
    0, (D[fun[t, x, y], y] /. y -> 1) == 0}, 
  fun[t, x, y], {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]


Plot3D[Evaluate[First[fun[5, x, y] /. solution]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
  1}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

And here is the error code

> NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of
>   140.65851971330582`at t = 5.` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid
>   spacing with 15 points may be too large to achieve the desired
>   accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid
>   spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method
>   options.

Please advise what can be done in such a situation. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The trouble is that in your `fun[5, x, y] /. solution` the pattern is not picked. Define `f[t_, x_, y_] = fun[t, x, y] /. First[solution]` and then plot `f[5,x,y]`.